# What does the word 'poets' mean in Tensorflow for poets?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

And what is the difference between TFLite Android and TFMobile Android?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"TensorFlow for Poets" is a take off of the "Physics for Poets" joke which is a reference to entry level courses on subjects having nothing to do with your career. "TensorFlow for Poets" is not an offical name, it just means a very simple introduction to TensorFlow

TensorFlow Mobile - original TensorFlow code for mobile devices, it is still around but being replaced with TensorFlow Lite.

TensorFlow Lite - New TensorFlow code for mobile and embedded devices. Under active development.

For more information on Mobile vs Lite: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkpaEPQtOwk @ 4:40